# How to programmatically send messages in HipChat?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, hipchat

My task is only to write a bookmarklet for simplifying editing messages in HipChat in my team. I wrote the following:

```
var id = document.querySelector('.hc-dropdown-trigger.aui-dropdown2-trigger.aui-button.aui-button-subtle.aui-dropdown2-trigger-arrowless.active.aui-dropdown2-active').id.slice(16, -8),
    msg = document.querySelector('[data-mid="' + id + '"]').innerText,
    evt = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent'),
    edit = prompt(msg, msg);

if ( edit !== null ) {
    document.getElementById('hc-message-input').value = 's/' + msg + '/' + edit;
    evt.initKeyEvent('keydown', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 13, 0);
    document.body.dispatchEvent(evt); // also tried dispatch on textearea itself
}
```

But nothing happens. How can I achive my goal?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

APIs exist so you don't have to do all this by hand. The HipChat API documentation is found at: https://www.hipchat.com/docs/apiv2

To send a message, take a look at https://www.hipchat.com/docs/apiv2/method/send_message